# Div next other, width are percents, paddings breaks the lines

Tags: css, html

I managed to create `div`s to act like a column of tables. However, now I want to padding between divs. If I do something like this:

```
<div style="float:left; width:100%;">
  <?php
  foreach ($datas as $rec) { ?>
  <div style="float:left; width:100%; background-color: green;">
    <div style="margin: 0px; float:left; width: 25%; background-color: red;"><a href="<?php echo $rec['HTTP']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $rec['LINKNAME']; ?></a></div>
    <div style="margin: 1px; background-color: yellow;"><?php echo $rec['DESCRIPTION']; ?></div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
  </div>
```

because of `margin: 1px` it falls apart. How to fix that?

Comment: Try setting the div with the green background width to 98%

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 solutions I can see to this:

1. Specify your margin as a percentage e.g. `margin:1%;`
2. Use the CSS3 `box-sizing` option e.g.

`webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */`

`-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */`

`box-sizing: border-box;`

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="float:left; width:100%;">
<?php
foreach ($datas as $rec) { ?>
    <div style="float:left; width:100%; background-color: green;">
        <div style="padding: 1px; float:left; width: 25%; background-color: red;"><a href="<?php echo $rec['HTTP']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $rec['LINKNAME']; ?></a></div>
        <div style="padding: 1px; background-color: yellow;"><?php echo $rec['DESCRIPTION']; ?></div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: like that, if the 2nd column has long text, it continuing next line, under the first column. So first column doesnt grow down